# Retrieve Image with Detail from DataBase and Bind with radListView in Block format in c# windows form Telerik

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radlistview

Current Out-Put of Application is :[image]

But i want that Out-Put show Like in below Format.
[image]

My App Code :

```
  #region 
    private DataTable dtbl { get; set; }
    public File_Related_Images(DataTable get_dtbl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtbl = get_dtbl;
        #region DataTable
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(Image));
        t.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
        t.Columns.Add("ImageName", typeof(string));
        t.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        foreach (DataRow row in dtbl.Rows)
        {
            Image img = ImageRetrive((byte[])row["ImageFile"]);
            int ID = int.Parse(row["ID"].ToString());
            string img_name = row["ImageName"].ToString();
            string description = row["Description"].ToString();
            t.Rows.Add(img, ID, img_name, description);
        }
        #endregion
        #region Bind DataTable with ListView DataSource
        lstv_Images.ItemDataBound += Lstv_Images_ItemDataBound;
        lstv_Images.DataSource = t;
        lstv_Images.DisplayMember = "ID";
        #endregion
        #region Group By Image Name
        lstv_Images.EnableGrouping = true;
        lstv_Images.ShowGroups = true;
        GroupDescriptor groupByValue = new GroupDescriptor(new SortDescriptor[] { new SortDescriptor("ImageName", ListSortDirection.Ascending) });
        lstv_Images.GroupDescriptors.Add(groupByValue);
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
    #region ItemDataBound
    private void Lstv_Images_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        e.Item.Image = rowView.Row["Image"] as Image;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Convert Byte Array to Image
    private Image ImageRetrive(byte[] rw)
    {
        byte[] imgData = rw;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    #endregion
```

So please help me that how to set my Application that get my required out-put from app. thanks all of you in advance.

Comment: please shrink your images before setting it to the grid and try once

Comment: Sir i use radListView , not a radGridView

Comment: sorry can you please resize all your images smaller like 150X150 and try if it works

Comment: Yes i tried but the result is same as above. and here the radListView  View type is "DetailsView"